# Why db.savechanges is storing the old records also?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have very weird problem

My code it works fine if I login and use then it save the preferences etc.

But problem starts when I login, do some selections, and logout and login as another user, then upon saving it also remembers the seelctions I had done wfor the other user, the last one and save that also.

How to prevent this?

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

...

  public IHttpActionResult Add(UserPreferencesDto model)
    {
        model.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var userPreferences = db.UserPreferences.Where(u =>
            u.UserId == model.UserId &&
            u.Key == model.Key.Trim())
          .FirstOrDefault();

        List<int> StatesCollection = new List<int>();

        var param = model.Value.Trim();
        string[] paramSplitted = param.Split(',');

        if (userPreferences != null)
        {              
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userPreferences.Value) == false)
            {
                var trimmedPreferenceValue = userPreferences.Value.Trim('[', ']');
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmedPreferenceValue) == false)
                {
                    StatesCollection = trimmedPreferenceValue.Split(',')
                      .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList<int>();
                }

                if (model.IsStateSelected == false && paramSplitted.Count() == 1 
                    && StatesCollection.Contains(int.Parse(param.Trim())))
                {
                    StatesCollection = StatesCollection.Where(sa => sa != int.Parse(param)).ToList<int>();
                    userPreferences.Value = StatesCollection.Count > 0 ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(StatesCollection) : "";
                }
                else if (model.IsStateSelected && paramSplitted.Count() == 1 
                    && !StatesCollection.Contains(int.Parse(param)))
                {
                    StatesCollection.Add(int.Parse(param));
                    userPreferences.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(StatesCollection);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                StatesCollection.Add(int.Parse(param));
                userPreferences.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(StatesCollection);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (model.IsStateSelected == true)
            {
                //string[] splittedStates = model.Value.Split(',');
                int[] secRolesIds = Array.ConvertAll(paramSplitted, int.Parse);
                model.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(secRolesIds);
                db.UserPreferences.Add(Mapper.Map<UserPreferences>(model));
            }

        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
```

Even if the preferences exist it goes to the last else.

Comment: Show the code where you create your `db` object

Comment: @CaiusJard done, check update.

Comment: it's insanity, i tried everything it happens.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code and validated, that the UserId is in fact different, after you've logged out and back in?

Comment: yes, different.

Comment: You didn't show where/when you create `db`. You need a new context for each run.

Comment: right after the class opening. in the start

Answer (score 0):

SaveChanges() in entity framework saves ALL tracked changes.

You would have to explicitly discard changes or use untracked entities, only adding them when you wish to save.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: I tried deattachign after db.savechanges but didn't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make the userPreferences variable null before giving a value to it, this way you could prevent it to have a value from the last execution because you would ensure it became null because you forced it to be. By doing so if there is no result in the database when you try to assign a value to it it will remain null for sure and so it will enter to the if with the if (userPreferences != null) and don't go to the else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi nice solution, but i tried and same issue.